# Add image elements in DOM using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some image files in a folder named imagefolder. The file names are in the form of number_of_suit.png (eg 7_of_diamond.png) and I want to add them to my html body. I think I have some syntax issues. An example in vanilla js..

```
var addImage = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
addImage.appendChild(img src = "imagefolder/ + number + "_of_" + suit.png");
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please mark as answer and vote up if this helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Basics**

You've got a couple of issues. To start, `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, not a `Node` so there is no `appendChild` element. To get around that, either get the first item of that collection, or simply get `document.body`:

```
var addImage = document.getElementsByTagName("body"); // NodeList
var bodyOne = addImage[0]; // <body> element
var bodyTwo = document.body; // <body> element
```

Secondly, if you see the syntax highlighting in your example, you can see that you're missing a couple of quotation marks.

```
var string = "imagefolder/" + number + "_of_" + suit + ".png";
```

Finally, as GottZ has pointed out, you can't just reference `img src` like you are. You need to create an `img` element and then set the `src` property.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = string;
```

**More Advanced**

You may have already handled this, we only have a small amount of your code to look at, but just in-case: you need to wait until the DOM has finished loading before you attempt to modify it. This is best done by waiting for the `DOMContentLoaded` event to fire.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Your work here.
});
```

Since you're going to be creating 52 elements, it would be more efficient to create a `DocumentFragment` and append all your new elements to that, appending the fragment to the body afterwards. This causes fewer re-paints in the browser so it is often much faster.

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
// ...
fragment.appendChild(img);
// ...
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

**Summing up**

The whole thing means your code will probably look something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    "use strict";

    var numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "king", "Ace"];
    var suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"];
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    suits.forEach(function (suit) {

        numbers.forEach(function (number) {

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "imagefolder/" + number + "_of_" + suit + ".png";
            fragment.appendChild(img);

        });

    });

    document.body.appendChild(fragment);

});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: i was in a hurry when i wrote my answer. yours sure reflects some efforts :D

Comment: wow thanks for such a detailed answer...learned a lot new today :)

Answer (score 2):

this is how you can append an image to the body:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("img")).src = "imagefolder/" + number + "_of_suit.png";
```

in order for this to work you need to make sure that your script runs after the body has been drawn.